# Python AtributeError _io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python, html, pandas, email, encode

I'm writing a code that sends emails to a list of mails from an .xlsx file.

I want the body of the email to be imported from a separate .html file, but i'm getting an encode error when it reaches line 47 (htmlPart = MIMEText(f, 'html'))

'_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'encode'

Here is my code:

```
from email.message import Message
import pandas as pd
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
  
your_email = "XXXXX"
your_password = "XXXXX"
  
server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
server.ehlo()
server.login(your_email, your_password)

message = MIMEMultipart("alternative")

email_list = pd.read_excel(r"C:\\Users\\fernando.martinez\\Desktop\\MAILS2.xlsx")
  
names = email_list['Name']
emails = email_list['Mail']
for i in range(len(emails)):
  
    name = names[i]
    email = emails[i]
  
    message = MIMEMultipart("alternative")

    message['From'] = your_email
    message['To'] = email
    message['Subject'] = "SUBJECT HERE"

    with open('emails.html', 'r') as f: 
        html_string = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]

    htmlPart = MIMEText(f, 'html')

    message.attach(htmlPart)

    server.send_message(message)

server.close()
```

Comment: Please provide a full traceback with the information on which line in your code (or imported module) is triggering this error.

Comment: the error triggers when it reaches line 47:
htmlPart = MIMEText(f, 'html')

Answer (score 0):

`with` opens and closes a file within the scope of its indented block. `htmlPart` is not inside the block - therefore the filehandle `f` is no longer associated with an open file.

However - `MIMEText()` expects a text string, not a filehandle as it's first argument. Given that you are generating `html_string` from `f` within the block, I expect you actually mean `MIMEText(html_string, 'html')`